# Anatomical Plausibility of Snake-Footed People

Tags: anatomy, humanoid, snake

The snake-footed people are, as the name implies, people with serpentine feet. Specifically, they have the muscles and bones of the lower part of a snake replacing their feet and part of their legs

This presents an issue for the anatomy: a snake's spine, the main support bone, is in the back, whereas the leg bones in humans are closer to the front. This is an issue, as it would prevent a solid connection for both the bones and muscles. Furthermore, the snake-feet could not be turned around, due to the nature of a snake's motion

The snake-footed people must have both human-like and truly snake-like anatomy in the legs

Is there any solution to this anatomical issue?

Comment: Please provide a diagram, it's far from clear what you're talking about.

Comment: Given that you already had an answer that you posted simultaneously with the question, what is the purpose of asking this question, rather than a reality check on the answer you posted?  To second @ARogueAnt. both the question and answer are unclear without diagrams

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 This question will help anyone else who is using snake-footed people for their own world

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I'll be able to make a diagram later

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 [Self-answers are allowed and encouraged](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). With that said, the question should be clear with out the answer. And I don't think it is - what part of the feet is actually a snake? And what part of a snake it is? I'm not sure what the problem here is nor how the answer actually solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Turn the legs

While the snake part can't turn, the human part can

The head of the femur is in the middle of the pelvis, and so there won't be any muscle issues from flipping it

The knees could also work flipped; There are many people who can bend their knees backwards, so it shouldn't take an unreasonable amount of alterations to make a functional reversed knee. Alternatively, you could simply ignore the knee and have it hold straight, as if there were no knee

The snake spine could then attach to the (now dorsal) tibia, which would serve as an attachment point to the human skeleton. The fibula is not needed in the snake-footed people